# Replacing starting single inverted by starting curly bracket and ending single inverted by ending curly bracket

Tags: mysql, sql, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc

I want to replace " ' "  by " { " & closing " ' " by " } ".
I have data in string in this format:

```
['Architecture & Planning', 
 'Banking', 
 'Financial Services', 
 'Financial Services', 
 'Internet', 
 'Hospitality', 
 'Marketing and Advertising']
```

But i want to display:

```
[
{
 'Architecture & Planning'
 }
 {
 'Banking'
 }
 {
'Financial Services'
 }
]
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: my input is : ['Architecture & Planning', 'Banking', 'Financial Services', 'Financial Services', 'Internet', 'Hospitality', 'Marketing and Advertising']  but i want output  [{'Architecture & Planning'},{ 'Banking'},{'Financial Services'},{'Internet'},{'Hospitality'},{ 'Marketing and Advertising'}] like this.